# Is my 'variable-storing area' basically a 'heap'?

Tags: low-level, virtual-machine, heap

I'm planning to implement a simple VM/interpreter kind of thing for a simple language I'm making. The compiler of the language emits mostly stack-oriented instructions to be executed by the VM.

The structure of the program will be something like this:

- The execution part (for lack of a better term): interprets the
  opcodes and executes them.
- The call stack: to keep track of function calling, and for parameter
  passing and return values.
- The data stack: for none function-calling-related computation, such as
  arithmetic.
- The variable-storing area, where variable names are matched with values.

The "variable-storing area" will be implemented basically with a HashTable/dictionary thing. When the programmer creates a variable (assuming for now only numeric variables), a new entry is added to the table. When he/she assigns a value to a variable, the entry with the matching name in the table is assigned this value. When the programmer accesses a variable, again we fetch the value from the table.

I'm pretty sure that's the only data-storing part I need in the application, aside from the data stack and the call stack. I don't see why I'd need anything else.

Now, I looked at what a 'heap' is in Wikipedia and other sources online. I found mostly technical terms that I'm having trouble understanding.

But in simpler non-very-technical terms, if I understand correctly, the heap is where the 'constant' data is saved, things that aren't local computation such as arithmetic.

So if my understanding is correct, is my 'variable-storing area' basically a 'heap'? Why or why not? If my understanding of what a heap is is wrong please explain it.

Comment: How are parameters different from any other variables? Do you plan to copy all parameters into your variable storage table when a function starts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term heap is tied to dynamic memory allocation. If your programs *dynamically* create "variables", your "variable storing area" might be considered a heap. But what one usually calls variables is far from dynamic:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
  int var = i * i;
}
```

Here at most three variables exist at any point in time. You'd have to write additional code to create more variables. The lifetime of all variables is very much statically determined. And so on.

The heap is *not* "all data, except constants". A common (simplified, of course) model of real computers is: You have registers and the stack (which house not only temporary values but also variables), memory that is statically allocated (i.e. exactly once for the entire time the program is running), and the heap for everything that doesn't fit in those categories. Usually variables and their values are not part of the heap at all, at most the variable values are references/pointers to data that's stored on the heap.

In this context, the stack is called stack because *allocations* are FIFO: When variables `a`, `b`, `c` were created in that order, `c` must be removed first before `b` and then `a` can be destroyed. But it's still random access memory, so accessing a variable looks like this in pseudo-C: `stackpointer[-10]` for the tenth value from the top of the stack.

A bytecode instruction `dec a` does not mean dynamic creation of variables in the sense used above. Obviously the memory management that makes room for the variable has to happen at run time, this is true even in C. But can a program perform a loop that creates a variable number of "variables"? If not, the set of variables is set in stone at the time the program is written and there is nothing dynamic about it.

Comment: I didn't understand a lot of this because I'm not familiar with low-level stuff. But I'll ask two specific questions: 1- a bit off topic, but why store variables on the stack? The stack is called that because at any time you can only access the uppermost value. So how is it convenient to store variables in it? 2- Pretty much my variables *are* dynamically created. The bytecode line `dec a` creates a new entry named `a` in the table, during runtime. And the line `ass a,5` looks up the entry `a` in the table and assigns it the value `5`. Would you consider this dynamic?

Comment: Also, as I said I don't see why my program, or any 'serious VM' for that matter, would need anything else apart from the parts I mentioned above. What's wrong with a simple 'table' to store variables, and at max two stacks for other operations? Why do VMs need a concept of a 'heap' like in hardware?

Comment: @Prog I tried to address (1) and (2) in an edit. Lastly, about the use of heap: How would you create a linked list or a tree data structure using only a fixed set of scalar variables?

Comment: If I understand correctly random access memory means the ability to reach any value in memory at the same amount of difficulty. So how is a stack random access memory? If I push `a`, then `b` and then `c`, reaching `a` and putting it back in is O(2) while reaching `c` (and putting everything back where it was) is O(6) I think. So I don't see why it's a good idea to use the stack to store variables. Also you need somewhere to store where the variables are from the top of the stack, right? Like some table. So why not store the values in that table? Why use a stack?

Comment: @Prog Let's talk C (and ignore the existence of registers). Specifically `void f() { int x; int y; ... }`. The prologue of the function will contain `add sp, 8` which advances the stack pointer by 8 bytes (actually more but let's ignore that too). `sp` is a pointer to the end/top of the stack **which is a region of RAM**. The compiler decided to put `x` first, so any time it needs to refer to `x` in the generated code, it loads and stores `[sp-8]` ("the value at the address stored in sp minus 4"), and for `y` it uses `[sp-4]`. This knowledge is deeply integrated into the generated code.

Comment: @Prog I also suggest you do some research on "low-level stuff" (there are some excellent questions on Stack Overflow and on this site). The VM will almost certainly look different (most VMs do) but it certainly doesn't hurt to know what real machines do.

Comment: @Prog, think about a recursive function. Where will you store your variables when the function calls itself?